# I'm trying to get value of a text input but it doesn't work correctly

Tags: javascript, html

When I use `document.getElementById()` it gives me the value but it doesn't put it in my created object

And here is my code:

```html
<script>
  var People = new Array();
  var counter = 0;

  function Add() {
    var fname = document.getElementById('Fname').value;
    var lname = document.getElementById('Lname').value;
    var age = document.getElementById('age').value;
    var person = {
      FirstName: fname,
      LastName: lname,
      Age: age
    };
    People[counter++] = person;
  }
</script>

<body>
  First Name <input type="text" name="Fname" id="Fname" /><br />
  Last Name <input type="text" name="Lname" id="Lname" /><br />
  Age <input type="text" name="age" id="age" /><br />
  <input type="button" value="Add" onclick="Add()" />
  <input type="button" value="Show" onclick="showP()" />
</body>
```

I would be grateful if you could help me fix my problem

Comment: What `console.log(person)` prints?

Comment: Your code works. I did not find any issue with it. Also the `person` object is added normally inside `People` array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not linking the `person` object with the people Array correctly. It seems that is what you attempted to do here with `People[counter++] = person;`

The correct way is:

```js
     <script>
      var People = []
      var counter = 0;

      function Add() {
        var fname = document.getElementById('Fname').value;
        var lname = document.getElementById('Lname').value;
        var age = document.getElementById('age').value;
        var person = {
          FirstName: fname,
          LastName: lname,
          Age: age
        };
       People.push(person)
       console.log(People)
       return People
      }
    </script>
```

You could also do this is if you inisist on your first method.

```js
  var People = new Array();
  var counter = 0;

  function Add() {
    var fname = document.getElementById('Fname').value;
    var lname = document.getElementById('Lname').value;
    var age = document.getElementById('age').value;
    var person = {
      FirstName: fname,
      LastName: lname,
      Age: age
    };

    People[counter] = person;
     ++counter 
    console.log(People)
  }
```

Comment: What's the use-case of `counter` ?

Comment: @MenaiAlaEddine from the original question. It would be the index, just like slotting the object into the Array at the given index and then increase the index every time. I wouldn't do this. But maybe it helps OP to understand what's happening with the code.